# How to make tf.contrib.learn.estimator not to add summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tf.contrib.learn.DNNClaisifer to train my models and meanwhile the estimator generate tensorflow summary in the model_dir which spent a lot of space. I failed to diable the summary since I couldn't find any arguments or interface to specify whether write the tensorflow summary. Could you tell me how to diable the summary writer in tf.contrib.learn.DNNClasifier?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no such option, but you can disable it from the [code](http://google3/third_party/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py?l=61). Remove the contents of `contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn._add_hidden_layer_summary`.